# How to copy all files with the same name into another directory using cp command

Tags: macos, terminal, cp

I have directory named "Documents". In this directory I have 5 files:

User1.txt

User2.txt

User3.txt

User4.txt

User5.txt

Users-info.zip

index.html

I want to copy only those files in whose names there is a word "user" to another directory. How I can do this with cp command?

Comment: Basic globbing `cp User* dirname` Or to copy only those with a number, `cp User[0-9]* dirname`

Comment: You should also spend time with the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) or [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html)

Comment: This title was a bit misleading to me. By "the same name," I assumed the files were exactly the same name and in different subfolders. Perhaps the title could be clarified with "How to copy all files with the same name prefix into another directory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case it is:

```
cp User[1-9].txt /dst_dir
```

We copy only files with `User` in the beginning, than some digit and finally `.txt`.

Comment: I think he wants `Users-info.zip` as well. Either way, he can choose what meets his needs. (you can use a bit more explanation as well `:)`

Comment: When I am using your command it says:  usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I am using OS X 10.9.5

Comment: But you have tag `linux` in your question. My answer is correct for linux OSs.

Comment: Ok, then what syntax for OS X?

Answer (score 2):

`cp User* /path/to/dir` try this, will be enough.

If you wish unusual way:

```
find . -type f -name 'User*' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /path/to/dir/for/copies/
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but a little more explanation than `"try this, will be enough."` is called for in any *Answer*, otherwise, leave a *Comment*.

Comment: When I use your command it says:   cp: user*: No such file or directory

Comment: @Alex first go to the "Documents" directory `cd Documents`. Or try `cp ~/Documents/User* /path/to/dir`

Comment: @ViktorKhilin Yes I am doing this in "Documents" directory but it still makes an error

Comment: mm, in your question files named *U*ser, nout user. You write command correctly, 'U' in 'User' is capital?

Comment: Yes, I am using capital letter 'U'

Comment: @Alex can you show me first output of `pwd` command, next `ls User1.txt` output and finally your `cp` command and it's output?

Comment: @ViktorKhilin /Users/Alex/documents
 User1.txt
 User2.txt
 User3.txt
 User4.txt
 User5.txt
 Users-info.zip
 index.html

Comment: I've seen you using Mac OS. I'm not sure about it syntax, so can you try command (cd into the directory with files first): `find . -type f -name 'User*' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /path/to/dir/for/copies/`